# Referencing A New Variable From A Different Method

Tags: c#, string

I'm new to C# and am making a text based game. In one method, I ask the player to answer an open ended question, and I store that response in a local variable called `response`. I would like to access the contents of the string `response` later on in a different method.

I, of course, run into problems here because `response` is a local variable and cannot be called outside of its initial method. I understand the idea of creating a new class and passing the string as an argument to be accessed in any method I choose, but how do I do this with a yet to be filled in string? Since the string `response` gets filled in by the player, how can I access the contents of that string in a different method?

I might just be missing something obvious here, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you want to see a variable between methods of the same class you declare a global class variable

Comment: @Steve maybe you mean a _member_ class variable? there is no global (class or not) variable in c#

Comment: I've actually solved it, but thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the response data in a location that both methods can access. They need to share the same `scope`. For example, if both methods belong to the same class, the natural way to let both methods access this data would be to declare a `field` in that class.

In this little example below `response` is declared as a field not a `local variable`. A (private) field's scope covers all methods and other members of a class.
Method `SetUserResponse` assigns a value to field "response" an method `ShowUserResponse` displays that value.

```
class Program
{
    private string response;
    
    static void Main(){
        var prog = new Program();
        prog.SetUserResponse();
        prog.ShowUserResponse();
    }

    private void SetUserResponse() { 
         Console.WriteLine("Enter something you think about");
         response = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private void ShowUserResponse() { 
         Console.WriteLine("You said you would think about: {0}", response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very straightforward and helpful response, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

your need is to have "something" that has a wider scope than a single method.
You have a few options:

1. You can return the `response` value and let the caller handle it the
   way it need it.

e.g.-

```
string response = "";
response = MyMethod();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

2. you can pass the variable by reference, e.g. `void MyMethod (ref string response)` and call it with something like

e.g.

```
string response = "";
MyMethod(ref response);
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

not the idiomatic way to do it, ref parameter are seldom used, usually in particular context requiring it

3. You can store the `response` value in a class member variable, so
   the caller will be able to access it. see lidqy answer as example.

As a general rule of thumb, the smaller the scope of a variable, the easier to handle it in code, it's easier to follow the code and understand when and how the variable is set.

So, if you just need to handle the value in the calling method (or bubbling the value a few method up), I'd go whith #1